# Can I add server side event handler to a link in Razorpages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action, inline, razor-pages

I have a bounch of links in Razorpages which is used to change status on an entry in SQL using EF.

```
<a>Set status 1</a>
<a>Set status 2</a>
<a>Set status 3</a>
```

I don't want to create one action for each status in my model, and do not want to add any routing. When clicking the status link it should run my C# code and return to the same page.

Is it possible to trigger an action inline in razorpages without adding a page-handler? (i.e adding a server side event handler to the links which execute the inline code)

Comment: What's wrong with routing?  How do you expect to use only one action for 3 different statuses without being able to differentiate which link was clicked?

Comment: Typically, links are meant for HTTPGET requests.. not HTTPPOST.  If you want to change the status of an entry and still stay on the same page, I would highly recommend using Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

First: No there is now way to do that. But there are work arounds.

I suggest creating one action with a parameter if you don't want multiple actions.

If you really want client side code to alter you DB you have to go the JavaScript route and access your DB via the JavaScript.

You have:

```
<a>Set status 1</a>
```

I suggest:

```
<a href="serverUrl/home/SetStatus?param=1">Set status 1</a>
```

In your home controller, (obviously you can change the controller)

```
    public ActionResult SetStatus(int param)
    {
        //do what ever.

        return RedirectToAction("OriginalAction");
    }
```

If you don't want it to redirect to the action then you would use ajax or something else to post it. I do this to post back the original latitude and longitude of a client without altering view. If you use an

```
<a />
```

you are going to change the URL and will have to redirect back to the original page.

Comment: please provde code for action with parameter using razorpages

Comment: why are you talking about "client side"

Comment: "access your DB via the JavaScript"...this is generally not possible if the DB is on the server, and even if it _is_ possible, it's horrendously insecure. Do you really mean by JavaScript making an AJAX to a server-side script?

Comment: No, I think  you got it all wrong.  I am asking if there is a way to execute server side code from a link directly in razorpages without using the model.  Using razor i can execute code upon rendering. But I want to execute it using a link